# Google Docs / Drive: Why are some Greek symbols not properly displayed?

Tags: google-drive, special-characters

My friend shared with me a Google document. This document includes some Greek symbols like tao, lambda, omega, sigma, etc. But I can't see these symbols! I also tried to search symbols by the menu `Insert -> Special characters` and this is what I see:

[image: G docs symbols]

UPDATE: How can I show these symbols?

Comment: The question is: why I can't see symbols? and what can I do to see them?

Comment: What operating system and browser are you using?

Comment: Windows Seven 32bit and the latest Google Chrome

Comment: @tyranitar, which font is being used? It looks like the font were damaged somehow.

Comment: The font I'm currently using is Arial, but the problem persists with all fonts! I have this problem using both my computers with latest Chrome. My desktop pc is Windows 7 64bit and the notebook is Windows 7 32bit

Answer (score 1):

insert, special characters, other European scripts, Greek.  Choose Greek from the drop-down menu to the right side of the "European Scripts" box.  It should show up.  If you can see Greek when browsing Wikipedia you should be able to see it in Google Docs.